# Find how many times the department of an employee has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table `Employee` storing any updates made on an employee:

```
EmployeeId DepartmentId Status       From       To 
44         30           Recruited    01/01/2017 06/03/2017
44         56           IN           07/03/2017 07/03/2018
44         67           IN           06/05/2018 06/09/2018
44         33           IN           07/09/2018 02/02/2019
44         33           OUT          03/02/2019 31/12/2019
44         45           Recruited    01/02/2020 03/02/2020
44         45           IN           04/02/2020 NULL
```

I want to count how many times each employee has changed his department knowing that the employee life cycle is like below : Recuited - IN - OUT
and the employees that left the company then went back to it like in this example.

Comment: And what would the answer be for this employee?

Comment: He changed his department 5 times and left the company then he went back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "Recruited", "In" and "Out" have to do with this.  If each row represents a  period of time when an employee was in a department, then use `lag()` to measure changes:

```
select employeeId, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(departmentId) over (partition by employeeId order by from_date) as prev_departmentId
      from t
     ) t
where prev_departmentId is null or prev_departmentId <> departmentId
group by employeeId;
```